# substitution in string

Tags: string, perl, substitution

I have the following string `./test`
and I want to replace it with `test`
so, I wrote the following in perl:
`my $t =~ s/^.//;`
however, that replaces `./test` with `/test`
can anyone please suggest how I fix it so I get rid of the `/` too. thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
my $t =~ s/^\.\///;
```

You need to escape the dot and the slash.

The substitution is `s/match/replace/`. If you erase, it's `s/match//`. You want to match "starts with a dot and a slash", and that's `^\.\/`.

Answer (score 4):

The dot doesn't do what you expect - rather than matching a dot character, it matches *any* character because of its special treatment. To match a dot and a forward slash, you can rewrite your expression as follows:

```
my $t =~ s|^\./||;
```

Note that you are free to use a different character as a delimiter, in order not to confuse it with any such characters inside the regular expression.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to get rid of `./` then you need to include both of those characters in the regex.

```
s/^\.\///;
```

Both `.` and `/` have special meanings in this expression (`.` is a regex metacharacter meaning "any character" and `/` is the delimiter for the `s///` operator) so we need to escape them both by putting a `\` in front of them.

An alternative (and, in my opinion, better) approach to the `/` issue is to change the character that you are using as the `s///` delimiter.

```
s|^\./||;
```

This is all documented in [perldoc perlop](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html).

Answer (score 2):

You have to use a backward slash before the dot and the forward slash: s/\.\//;
The backslash is used to write symbols that otherwise would have a different meaning in the regular expression.

Answer (score 2):

You need to write `my $t =~ s/^\.\///;` (Note that the period needs to be escaped in order to match a literal period rather than any character).  If that's too many slashes, you can also change the delimiter, writing instead, e.g., `my $t =~ s:^\./::;`.

Answer (score 2):

```
$t=q(./test);$t=~s{^\./}{};print $t;
```

You need to escape the dot if you want it to match a dot.  Otherwise it matches any character.  You can choose alternate delimiters --- best when dealing with forward slashes lest you get the leaning-toothpick look when you otherwise need to escape those too.

Answer (score 2):

Note that the dot in your question is matching any character, not a literal '.'.

```
my $t = './test';
$t =~ s{\./}{};
```

Answer (score 2):

```
use Path::Class qw( file );
say file("./test")->cleanup();
```

[Path::Class](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Path%3a%3aClass)